# Print Range value inside MsgBox without loop in VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, vba, microsoft-excel-2007, printing

I have a problem with Excel vba that I want to print range value inside message box like

```
MsgBox "Sheets("sheet1").Range("A1:D1")
```

I know it is possible with loop like with cell like

```
for i=1 to 4
MsgBox "Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1,i)
next i
```

Is there any way that I can be able to perform this Operation with out loop in VBA

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need a loop:

```
Sub test()
    Dim r As Range, ary
    Set r = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:D1")
    ary = Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(r.Value))
    MsgBox Join(ary, " ")
End Sub
```

[image]

Or:

```
Sub test()
    Dim r As Range, ary
    Set r = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:D1")
    With Application
         MsgBox Join(.Transpose(.Transpose(r)), " ")
    End With
End Sub
```

**EDIT#1:**

If you have **Excel 365** you could use:

```
Sub test365()
    Dim r As Range, ary
    Set r = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:D1")
    With Application
         MsgBox .TextJoin(" ", True, r)
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a message box for each cell in the range, the best you can do *is* a loop.

The loop you provided would work, but the following might be better since it also processes ranges consisting of multiple rows:

```
Dim var As Variant

For Each var In Sheets("sheet1").Range("A1:D2")
    MsgBox var
Next var
```